# An usable call log for Android

Tags: android, logs, phone

The [stock Google phone app](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.dialer&hl=en) has many features but, for some obscure reason, has not a detailed call log. It shows the date of the call, but not the time.

Which **dialer app with an actually usable call log** would you suggest to replace it? Or, if possible, do you know of any app that is able to show the **detailed call log**?

Answer (score 1):

Try [truecaller](https://www.truecaller.com/features),

It is not just a caller and logger it will let you know in real time what is the status of other caller like they are on call or busy.

It will tell you if a call is spam or business call.

Feature listed from their website:

- Caller ID
- Spam Blocking
- Intelligent dialer
- Record phone calls

Side note: they have pretty dense requirement for user privacy information.

Comment: Thanks. I've tried the app but privacy-wise it's too demanding, so I'm not going to use it. Edited the question.

Answer (score 0):

found some app [Recent Call Log](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=jon.brown4) but i am not satisfied because it ask for unnecessary permissions, and incoming only view is missing